# Is there any documentation for the JSON "array path" notation? "jsonb#>{x, y, z}"

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to gather information around the "array notation" (for a lack of a better name) that's used to "select"/"target" keys in a JSON blob.

I'm specifically talking about the `'{a, b, c}'` notation that you can use with the `#>` operator.

The [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html) gives a couple of usage examples, such as:

```sql
'{"a": {"b":{"c": "foo"}}}'::json#>'{a,b}' // {"c": "foo"}
```

or

```sql
'{"a": {"b": [1, 2]}}'::json#>'{a,b,1}' // 2
```

But nothing beyond these very basic examples. I couldn't even find a proper name for this API.

Here are my questions:

- Do you know any proper documentation on the subject
- If not, do you know any features of that API that go beyond the two very simple examples mentioned above? (Meaning: selecting deep keys & selecting an array index) Can it be of any different shape?

We're trying to evaluate whether we can safely parse a string of shape `"{a, b, c}"` to an array of `["a", "b", "c"]` that we could send to our Postgres driver.

Thanks for taking the time to answer me.
Cheers!

Comment: While I am not familiar with postgresql, wouldn't this fit in for string manipulation? The reason being, the input text `"{a, b, c}"` isnt a valid json.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: the right hand side of that operator isn't a JSON value, but a string _array_ and `'{a,b,1}'` is a valid array constant in Postgres

Comment: `{a,b,1}` is a valid array constant? I mean, is `a` or `b` a variable? Should not be quoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be about the array input syntax, not the #> operator itself.  PostgreSQL arrays are a generic feature and used in many places other than in JSON contexts.  The input syntax for PostgreSQL arrays [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO).  Since PostgreSQL knows that #> takes an array of strings on its RHS, it knows to treat the construct as an array of strings without you needing to add a cast. There are other ways of doing it, for example you could replace `'{a,b,1}'` with `ARRAY['a','b','1']`.

Many drivers will provide a way to directly bind an array (or array reference) to a single placeholder.  For help specifically with your driver, you would need to identify it.

Comment: Thanks, this answer and the one above were the ones I was looking for! Last question maybe: Is there any use of multi-dimensional arrays when passed as the right value of the `#>` operator for extracting json?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "name" for this, as this is completely "made up" by the Postgres developers.

The `#>` (or `#>>`) operator is simply a shorthand for chaining multiple `->` operators.

So

```
'{"a": {"b": [1, 2]}}'::jsonb  #> '{a,b,1}'
```

is the same as

```
(('{"a": {"b": [1, 2]}}'::jsonb -> 'a') -> 'b') -> 1
```

The parentheses aren't really necessary, I just added them to make it more obvious that the second `->` uses the result of the first `->`